# How to upgrade to chrome 64 bit?

Tags: macos, upgrade, google-chrome, 64-bit

Finally there should be a version of Chrome 64 bit for Mac.

I received an email from google groups:

> Switch the Mac build from 32-bit to 64-bit.
>
> As of M39, Chrome is a 64-bit only binary. This changes the default
>   build configuration to 64-bit globally. After this CL, the 32-bit Mac
>   build is no longer supported.

Now, while this is good news, I wonder how to do that without losing all my bookmarks, cookies, passwords that are in my current version of Chrome

Can somebody help?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. It is still the same program and will continue to use your existing profile. It's the same as any other version upgrade, just this one happens to be transitioning from 32- to 64-bit.

Comment: @tubedogg Okay, but then it says that chrome is fully upgraded in the About section?

Comment: If it's says it's up to date, then it is. I don't know where you received that email from exactly, but it likely has not hit the release channel yet.

Comment: @tubedogg It is not the 64 bit version, that is for sure. Probably the 64 bit update it's not ready yet in my language, I'll just have to wait!

Answer (score 1):

Chrome is updated automatically by a process that runs in the background. Though sometimes I have to launch it and update it from the"About Chrome" menu selection, that may me being to picky avoid what Little Snitch tells me about...

Anyway you don't (or shouldn't) have to do anything, it will update all by itself with no loss of anything. Just check "About Chrome" in the Chrome menu.

Comment: I did, multiple times (I received the email 4-5 days ago). Usually it updates by himself and I just need to restart it, but this time it says that Chrome is upgraded. My guess is that for the 64 bit version one would have to download it separately? Don't know actually

Comment: Just checked on Mavericks, and it was updated automatically to 64 in About -Version 39.0.2171.65 (64-bit)

Comment: @Buscar웃 I just checked, mine says it is updated - Version 38 though. I'll probably have to wait then.. maybe it is not available yet in my language

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Google's Manual Update to see if a Version is available for your Language.

```
In Finder, select Go > Go to Folder.
In the window that appears, enter one of the following locations. It's expected that one of these folders won't be found:
    /Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/
    ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/Resources/
In the folder that opens, double click the file named 'CheckForUpdatesNow.command'.
```